# How to import cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble importing cloud firestore using eslint standard import. The cloud firestore web example uses 'require'. How do you use it with import?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```